# How to import C++ files in to android studio without gradle?

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cocos2d-x

I've imported a cocos2d-x project to my `android studio` IDE, just only android files were imported. Now I have to make some code in both Java files(in android) and C++ files(which are located in `Class` folder), and I want to import `Class` folder in to android studio. How can I do this without using gradle(because there is no gradle file when I imported this cocos2d-x project)?

Comment: what about copy and past, because you just want the classes ?

Comment: Yes, I have done like your suggestion, but when I compile, the C++ code seemed not run(when I make some changes in C++ code)

Comment: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Comment: I saw this guide using gradle, but my project have no gradle file :(

Comment: Why can you build a gradle using android studio ?

Comment: As I said before, when I imported cocos2d-x project in to android studio, it had no gradle. I followed [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLeGy1foMQA)